# Removing arrow on battery circuittikz

Tags: circuitikz

When I use the battery symbol and specify a voltage it draws a directional arrow above the battery symbol, which I want to remove.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{component/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=white,minimum size =0.75cm,inner sep=0pt}}

\begin{circuitikz}[european]
\draw (0,0) to [battery1=9V] (3,0); 
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `to[battery1=...]` is translated as `to[battery1,v=...]` by default. whereas `to[battery1,l=...]` is what you want.  Note: this is a component dependent feature and comes from the definition of `battery1/.style`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{component/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=white,minimum size =0.75cm,inner sep=0pt}}

\begin{circuitikz}[european]
\draw (0,0) to [battery1,l=9V] (3,0); 
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I think you mean `to[battery1,l=...]`  and not `to[battery1,v=...]`, like in the code. Normal label:  `l=` [6.3 Labels and custom twoport boxes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz)

Comment: @Bobyandbob - I hope I made my explanation more clear now.